# NSTableView error -[__NSCFConstantString setFrame:]

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

all. when I use NSTableView, it will give me the following errors as long as it reaches in this function.

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

USBInfor* usbInfor = [_tableContent objectAtIndex:row];
NSString* identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

return [usbInfor valueForKey:identifier];
}
```

I created a usbInfor class to save name, size, path, and type of USB. And I add those variables into _tableContent NSMutableArray.

```
 USBInfor *usbinfor = [[USBInfor alloc]init];
 usbinfor.name = [mountPath substringFromIndex:9];
 usbinfor.path = mountPath;
 usbinfor.size = formattingSize;
 usbinfor.type = type;

 [_tableContent addObject:usbinfor];
```

I created 3 columns in xib file and each of the identifier I named the same as the variables' name which are name, path, and size.

Here are the errors:

```
 2013-05-08 22:56:34.157 TESTING[7760:303] -[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized      selector sent to instance 0x10022a3d0
 2013-05-08 22:56:34.158 TESTING[7760:303] An uncaught exception was raised
 2013-05-08 22:56:34.159 TESTING[7760:303] -[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized  selector sent to instance 0x10022a3d0
 2013-05-08 22:56:34.162 TESTING[7760:303] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e8ab06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff81a003f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81f2140a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e7902e ___forwarding___ + 414
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e78e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c456a73 -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] + 533
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c45666f -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] + 151
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c454c05 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 415
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c45498a -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] + 272
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c453c59 -[NSTableRowData _unsafeUpdateVisibleRowEntries] + 740
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c4537f1 -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 119
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c42b87b -[NSTableView viewWillDraw] + 165
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c393aa5 -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] + 45
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308584 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1525
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2d49b1 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1044
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c391a48 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1377
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c391068 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 940
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c390c4f -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 159
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c292266 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1424
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c27114d loadNib + 317
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c270679 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 219
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3c35bc +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 140
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c270398 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 626
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c26ca2f NSApplicationMain + 398
36  TESTING                             0x00000001000012b2 main + 34
37  TESTING                             0x0000000100001264 start + 52
)
 2013-05-08 22:56:34.164 TESTING[7760:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10022a3d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e8ab06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff81a003f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81f2140a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e7902e ___forwarding___ + 414
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e78e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c456a73 -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] + 533
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c45666f -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] + 151
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c454c05 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 415
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c45498a -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] + 272
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c453c59 -[NSTableRowData _unsafeUpdateVisibleRowEntries] + 740
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c4537f1 -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 119
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c42b87b -[NSTableView viewWillDraw] + 165
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c393aa5 -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] + 45
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3091ed __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff81e834a6 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308f2d -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c308584 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1525
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2d49b1 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1044
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c391a48 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1377
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c391068 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 940
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c390c4f -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 159
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c292266 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1424
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c27114d loadNib + 317
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c270679 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 219
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c3c35bc +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 140
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c270398 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 626
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c26ca2f NSApplicationMain + 398
36  TESTING                             0x00000001000012b2 main + 34
37  TESTING                             0x0000000100001264 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

**It has to run under OS X 10.5 and the base SDK OS X 10.7**

Thanks !!

Comment: “It has to run under OS X 10.5…” Then you shouldn't use view-based table views. Those were introduced in Lion (10.7). They will not work on Leopard (10.5) or Snow Leopard (10.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method, tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: needs to return an NSView or a subclass of NSView. It looks like [usbInfor valueForKey:identifier], where identifier is "name", returns a string ([mountPath substringFromIndex:9]). I don't know what you're trying to do there, but that's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[tableColumn identifier] is used to identify a column name.  So it should be something like

```
NSString *filename = [[itemArray1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:key1a];
NSString *path = [[itemArray1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:key1b];

NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
if ([identifier] isEqualToString:@"whatever a column name is"]) {
    return filename;
}

else if ([identifier] isEqualToString:@"whatever a column name is"]) {
    return path;
}

...
```